# Cannot install dsniff in 9.10 USB

Tags: usb, package-management, 9.10, fat32

Ubuntu 9.10 USB Pendrive everything works good even after `sudo apt-get update` and I try to `sudo apt-get install dsniff` and I get the following message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install dsniff
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package dsniff
```

It's not finding the package for some weird reason. Please help I like 9.10 Ubuntu and want Dsniff to run on this failing to fetch packages.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't find the package you want is because 9.10 has reached its end of life and its repository has been removed - actually its been moved.

You can follow the instructions provided in this question and answer for installing `dsniff` for 9.10.

- [Installing software on an old Ubuntu version that's no longer supported](https://superuser.com/questions/301432/installing-software-on-an-old-ubuntu-version-thats-no-longer-supported-2009-ja)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install dsniff from a deb package.
http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dsniff